# How to override Serilog logger in Autofac child scope?

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, serilog, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a basic .NET Core Generic Host that uses Serilog and Autofac.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var configuration = CreateConfiguration(args);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        try 
        {
            Log.Information("Starting host...");

            await new HostBuilder()
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(cb => cb.AddConfiguration(configuration))
                .ConfigureServices((ctx, sc) => {
                    sc.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog());
                })
                .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(cb => { 
                    cb.RegisterModule(new AppModule()); 
                })
                .RunConsoleAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    private static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration(IReadOnlyCollection<string> args) 
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddUserSecrets<Program>(true)
            .AddCommandLine(args.ToArray())
            .Build();
    }
}
```

`AppModule` is an Autofac module where I register a `IHostedService`

```cs
internal class AppModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(
                ctx => {
                    var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                    return new AutofacHostedServiceScopeOwner(
                        () => c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()
                            .BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.Register(x => Log.Logger.ForContext("name", "value")).As<Serilog.ILogger>()),
                        scope => new MessageProcessingService(
                            scope.Resolve<ILogger<MessageProcessingService>>()
                        )
                    );
                }
            )
            .As<IHostedService>();
    }
}
```

This part looks complicated, but what I am trying to accomplish is to run `MessageProcessingService` (an `IHostedService` implementation) in an Autofac child scope so that I can override the resolved logger within the entire `MessageProcessingService` graph with some context specific information. There will be multiple `MessageProcessingService` instances and each requires a logger with unique context so that I can correlate log output.

I use `AutofacHostedServiceScopeOwner` to wrap `MessageProcessingService` in a child scope. There is probably a better way to do this, but it's the best I could come up with.

```cs
public class AutofacHostedServiceScopeOwner : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Func<ILifetimeScope> _scopeFactory;
    private readonly Func<ILifetimeScope, IHostedService> _serviceFactory;
    private ILifetimeScope _currentScope;
    private IHostedService _hostedService;

    public AutofacHostedServiceScopeOwner(Func<ILifetimeScope> scopeFactory, Func<ILifetimeScope, IHostedService> serviceFactory) {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        _currentScope = _scopeFactory();
        _hostedService = _serviceFactory(_currentScope);
        await _hostedService.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        if (_hostedService != null)
            await _hostedService.StopAsync(cancellationToken);

        _currentScope?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _currentScope?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is all working correctly, except the resolved logger does not contain the expected context properties. This makes me think that my override logic is wrong, but I'm not sure what else to try.

```
c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()
    .BeginLifetimeScope(
        b => b.Register(x => Log.Logger.ForContext("name", "value")).As<Serilog.ILogger>()
    )
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Swapping out the whole logger factory seems expensive. Did you consider [custom enrichers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) instead?

Comment: @TravisIllig I considered it, but wasn't sure how to apply the enricher to a single scope. I also tried LogContext.PushProperty, wasn't able to figure that out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after hours of banging my head against the wall.

```c#
builder.Register(
        ctx => {
            var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return new AutofacHostedServiceScopeOwner(
                () => c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()
                    .BeginLifetimeScope(
                        b => {
                            b.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>));
                            b.Register(
                                    x => new SerilogLoggerFactory(
                                        Log.Logger.ForContext("name", "value")
                                    )
                                )
                                .As<ILoggerFactory>()
                                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                        }
                    ),
                scope => new MessageProcessingService(
                    scope.Resolve<ILogger<MessageProcessingService>>()
                )
            );
        }
    )
    .As<IHostedService>();
```

The reason this works is because in `Program.cs` the logger configuration call `sc.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog())` registers `ILogger<>` and `ILoggerFactory` as singletons under the covers. The `lb.AddSerilog()` call registers a Serilog provider which is used by the `ILoggerFactory`, but I was not able to find any way to override the provider specifically so I replaced them all.

Hopefully this helps someone.